# Create boolean columns in DataFrame pandas for date and year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Let it be the following Python Panda DataFrame:

| code | date | color | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TTT | 2021-02-01 00:30:11 | blue | 2 |
| AVC | 2022-02-01 10:00:01 | red | 12 |
| BCH | 2022-02-02 22:00:01 | red | 12 |
| POD | 2022-03-01 01:00:03 | blue | 1 |
| UDY | 2022-05-01 09:02:01 | red | 3 |
| YUD | 2022-12-01 09:02:01 | green | 0 |

I need to create a column by year and month that includes whether or not that row belongs (bool) to the specific month indicated in the column. An example of the resulting DataFrame is as follows:

| code | date | color | counter | 2021-02 | 2022-02 | 2022-03 | 2022-05 | 2022-12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TTT | 2021-02-01 00:30:11 | blue | 2 | True | False | False | False | False |
| AVC | 2022-02-01 10:00:01 | red | 12 | False | True | False | False | False |
| BCH | 2022-02-02 22:00:01 | red | 12 | False | True | False | False | False |
| POD | 2022-03-01 01:00:03 | blue | 1 | False | False | True | False | False |
| UDY | 2022-05-01 09:02:01 | red | 3 | False | False | False | True | False |
| YUD | 2022-12-01 09:02:01 | green | 0 | False | False | False | False | True |

To solve the problem only the information in the `date` column is used, but I include the complete DataFrame to avoid incompatibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `df.to_period` with `str.get_dummies`

```py
out = df.join(pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period("M")
              .astype(str).str.get_dummies()
              .astype(bool))
```

```
print(out)

  code                 date  color  counter  2021-02  2022-02  2022-03  2022-05  2022-12
0  TTT  2021-02-01 00:30:11   blue        2     True    False    False    False    False
1  AVC  2022-02-01 10:00:01    red       12    False     True    False    False    False
2  BCH  2022-02-02 22:00:01    red       12    False     True    False    False    False
3  POD  2022-03-01 01:00:03   blue        1    False    False     True    False    False
4  UDY  2022-05-01 09:02:01    red        3    False    False    False     True    False
5  YUD  2022-12-01 09:02:01  green        0    False    False    False    False     True
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for `YYYY-MM` format and parameter `dtype` for booleans:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'), dtype=bool))
print (df)
  code                date  color  counter  2021-02  2022-02  2022-03  \
0  TTT 2021-02-01 00:30:11   blue        2     True    False    False   
1  AVC 2022-02-01 10:00:01    red       12    False     True    False   
2  BCH 2022-02-02 22:00:01    red       12    False     True    False   
3  POD 2022-03-01 01:00:03   blue        1    False    False     True   
4  UDY 2022-05-01 09:02:01    red        3    False    False    False   
5  YUD 2022-12-01 09:02:01  green        0    False    False    False   

   2022-05  2022-12  
0    False    False  
1    False    False  
2    False    False  
3    False    False  
4     True    False  
5    False     True
```